# Generate histograms out of dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that I want to `group_by()` and generate a histogram for each group. My current code is as follows:

```
df %>%
  group_by(x2) %>%
  with(hist(x3,breaks = 50))
```

This however generates a single histogram of the entirety of x3 rather than several chunks of x3 here is some example data

```
df = data.frame(x1 = rep(c(1998,1999,2000),9),
            x2 = rep(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),3),
            x3 = rnorm(27,.5))
```

desired output:

[image]

actual output:

[image]

Comment: Base R functions such as `hist` don't care about dplyr's `group_by`.

Comment: `?do` should help

Comment: hist only takes a column of data, it's ignoring your grouping. Use ggplot instead or do

Comment: @infominer OP pipes to `with`, which takes the full data frame. The problem is that functions from outside `dplyr` ignore the grouping---this is just as true for `ggplot` as it is for `with` or `hist`.

Comment: @Gregor, ya that too. Noticed it after I typed my comment. with ggplot they will have to facet or have the ability to use fill to color the bars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My comment about `do`  is dated, I guess. `?do` points us to the current `?group_walk`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(x2) %>%
 group_walk(~ hist(.x$x3))
```

In versions of `dplyr` < 0.8.0, there is no `group_walk`, so you can use `do`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(x2) %>%
  do(h = hist(.$x3))
```

Assuming you only want the side-effects of `hist` (printed histogram), not the returned values, you can add a `%>% invisible()` to the end of the chain to not print the resulting tibble.

Comment: Where does `group_walk` come from? `sos::findFn('group_walk')` found 0 matches.

Comment: It's a dplyr function, you may have to update to the most recent package version.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I guess it was new in dplyr 0.8.0. I'll add a `do` version for backwards compatability.

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I wanted. is it possible to pass other arguments within the `group_walk()` call? For example changing the main title to be whatever the grouping variable is? Something like `main = .x$x2' (that syntax doesn't work something about "unknown or uninitialized column) -edit- figured it out, need to initialized the column with .y$x2

Comment: Thanks. In the mean time I have updated package `dplyr`.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's time to advance to ggplot, for instance:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x3)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 50) + 
  facet_wrap(~x2) # optional: use argument "ncols = 1"
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, the OP *did* include sample data

Comment: `facet_grid(rows = vars(x2))` is more consistent with the OP's expected output. And in the OP's data creation code I have added a zero to each column vector.

Comment: I don't see anything listed in the post's edit history though. Don't mean it as a fault with your post

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split.data.frame` command to split the data based on the categories after this you run a hist command in the list of data frames

```
list_df <- split.data.frame(df, f= df$x2)
par(mfrow = c(round(length(list_df), 0), 1))

for( lnam in names(list_df)){
  hist(list_df[[lnam]][, "x3"])

}
```

Comment: `split` is an S3 function, so if you just use `split(df, f = df$x2)` it will dispatch `split.data.frame` for you.

Answer (score 2):

I really like @Gregor's answer with `group_walk`, but it's still listed as experimental in `dplyr` v0.8.0.1. If you want to avoid working with functions that may break later, I'd use base `split`, then `purrr::walk`. I'm using `walk` and `plot` to avoid all the text printout that `hist` gives.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  split(.$x2) %>%
  walk(~hist(.$x3) %>% plot())
```

Comment: Nice answer! Consider `%>% invisible` as a more direct/general way to avoid text output.